# How can I enable detailed metrics (read, write, cache) for MySQL on GCP?

Tags: mysql, logging, google-cloud-platform, metrics, stackdriver

Currently I only see MySQL errors and user connections being logged. How can I enable more detailed logs in order to generate metrics?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah okay, those metrics are stored in the database itself, not logged. Which makes more sense, but it was just a bit hidden where the Cloud Console was exposing them.

In your list of Cloud SQL instances, **instead of clicking into an instance**, you want to **select the checkbox next to the instance**, which will bring up an "Info" panel on the right, from which you can select different metrics.

I'm guessing these metrics don't integrate into the Metrics Explorer.

[image]